# Angular2 cli - newly created app not clean in Safari

Tags: angular, safari, angular-cli

I am using angular-cli to create new app. After executing build (regardless of dev or prod) app works as expected in Chrome or FireFox, however when open in Safari it gives me an error every time.

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'safari.application.addEventListener')
```

Regardless for error app continue to work as expected. What is causing this error and how to prevent it - want to have app clean in modern browsers ?

Comment: Maybe this might give you a clue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078708/safari-extension-safari-application-error

Comment: Maybe the error is not from the app but from a Safari extension that you have see the usage of  `safari.application.addEventListener` in extension development https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/MessagesandProxies/MessagesandProxies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH14-SW1

Comment: Have you tried the new version with Webpack  module loader (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/WEBPACK_UPDATE.md)?