# Wait for message to send in window.onbeforeunload?

Tags: javascript, safari, safari-extension

I'm messing around with Safari extensions, and I'd like my extension to respond to the user opening or closing tabs.

I have the extension injecting a script that runs when the new tab opens and notifies the global page that there's a new tab open. I want the script to also notify the global page when the tab closes. To do this, I'm having the injected script set the `window.onbeforeunload` function to call `safari.self.tab.dispatchMessage`. This works, but the problem is the tab closes and the Javascript gets killed before the message goes through. If, for example, I put an `alert` after the `dispatchMessage` to prevent the tab from closing until the user clicks OK, the message goes through fine, but this obviously isn't a very good user experience.

Is there a way to buy a little extra time right before the tab closes, or is there a better function to override for this or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that all messages save one (`canLoad`) are asynchronous. IMO, the `canLoad` is a bit of a hack itself, but I've used it effectively when I desperately need synchronous messaging for some reason. I asked an [analogous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026686/safari-extension-questions) a while back that may help illustrate the `canLoad` solution/hack.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, abusing `canLoad` is pretty hacky, but there's not much else one can do.